# Changing Conditional Formatting colors using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background, conditional-formatting

First, for people who say that I should be using themes, I know.  However, themes allow for only 6 accent colors, and I need at least 10. (20 would be nice).

So I have a whole bunch of custom colors, which are not theme colors.  Is there anyway to access custom colors and change them based on their value?  for example if it equals a specific hex value, can i change it to another, globally.

or, alternatively, can i change custom formatting colors through appscript.

`sheet.getConditionalFormatRules().forEach(sh=>{ sheetC.getRange(r, 10).setValue(sh.getBooleanCondition().getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() ); if (sh.getBooleanCondition().getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() == "#87cbd7") { sheetC.getRange(r, 9).setValue("->" ); } r = r+1; })`

this line is there to make sure the if statement is working properly:
sheetC.getRange(r, 9).setValue("->" );

but I want to use that line to change this color:
sh.getBooleanCondition().getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString()

Help??

Thanks,
LJ

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is there anyway to access custom colors and change them based on their value? for example if it equals a specific hex value, can i change it to another, globally. or, alternatively, can i change custom formatting colors through appscript.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.